# how to parse some C-language block comments(with good format) using ANTLRv4

Tags: antlr4

I need to paese C source code with formated block comments like below.
I want extract those fileds:"abcd", "filedname1", "attr1", "attr2","filedname2", "attr1", "attr2".

I've write a gramma file like below, but its "BlockComment" could not get the normal block comments, still I'm not sure the gramma file is correct?
Any one can help me, Thanks!

```
/*
*| abcd {
*|  .filename1
*|  {
*|    :attr1= define;
*|    :attr2= "Cell#";
*|  }
*|  .filename2
*|  {
*|    :attr1= define;
*|    :attr2= "Cell#";
*|  }
*| }
*/
```

The gramma file blow:
grammar caldef;

```
grammar caldef;
caldefBodyList
    : caldefBody
    ;

caldefComment
    :  CaldefCommentStart CaldefLineStart Identifier LeftBrace caldefBodyList CaldefEnd1* CaldefCommentEnd
    ;

caldefBody
    : CaldefLineStart  Identifier CaldefLineStart LeftBrace caldefFiledBodyList CaldefEnd1
    ;

caldefFiledBodyList
    : caldefFiledBody
    | caldefFiledBodyList caldefFiledBody
    ;

caldefFiledBody
    : CaldefLineStart Whitespace? Colon Identifier ';'
    | CaldefLineStart Whitespace? Colon Identifier assignmentOperator StringLiteral+';'
    | CaldefLineStart Whitespace? Colon Identifier assignmentOperator Identifier';'
    ;

assignmentOperator
    :   '=' | '*=' | '/=' | '%=' | '+=' | '-=' | '<<=' | '>>=' | '&=' | '^=' | '|='
    ;
BlockComment
    :  '/*'[ \r\t]*?'\n'~[*|].*? '*/'
    ;

CaldefCommentStart
    :  '/*'[ \r\t]*?'\n'
    ;

CaldefEnd1
        : '*|'[ \t]*?'}'
        ;

CaldefCommentEnd
    : '*/'
    ;

CaldefLineStart
    : '*|'
    ;

LineComment
    :   '//' ~[\r\n]*
        -> skip
    ;
StringLiteral
    :   EncodingPrefix? '"' SCharSequence? '"'
    ;
    fragment
EncodingPrefix
    :   'u8'
    |   'u'
    |   'U'
    |   'L'
    ;

fragment
SCharSequence
    :   SChar+
    ;
    fragment
SChar
    :   ~["\\\r\n]
    |   EscapeSequence
    ;
fragment
EscapeSequence
    :   SimpleEscapeSequence
    |   OctalEscapeSequence
    |   HexadecimalEscapeSequence
    |   UniversalCharacterName
    ;

fragment
SimpleEscapeSequence
    :   '\\' ['"?abfnrtv\\]
    ;

fragment
OctalEscapeSequence
    :   '\\' OctalDigit
    |   '\\' OctalDigit OctalDigit
    |   '\\' OctalDigit OctalDigit OctalDigit
    ;

fragment
HexadecimalEscapeSequence
    :   '\\x' HexadecimalDigit+
    ;
fragment
BinaryConstant
    :   '0' [bB] [0-1]+
    ;

fragment
DecimalConstant
    :   NonzeroDigit Digit*
    ;

fragment
OctalConstant
    :   '0' OctalDigit*
    ;

fragment
HexadecimalConstant
    :   HexadecimalPrefix HexadecimalDigit+
    ;

fragment
HexadecimalPrefix
    :   '0' [xX]
    ;

fragment
NonzeroDigit
    :   [1-9]
    ;

fragment
OctalDigit
    :   [0-7]
    ;

fragment
HexadecimalDigit
    :   [0-9a-fA-F]
    ;

Whitespace
    :   [ \r\t]+
        -> skip
    ;
LeftParen : '(';
RightParen : ')';
LeftBracket : '[';
RightBracket : ']';
LeftBrace : '{';
RightBrace : '}';
Question : '?';
Colon : ':';
Semi : ';';
Comma : ',';
Newline
    :   (   '\r' '\n'?
        |   '\n'
        )
        -> skip
    ;

Identifier
    :   IdentifierNondigit
        (   IdentifierNondigit
        |   Digit
        )*
    ;

fragment
IdentifierNondigit
    :   Nondigit
    |   UniversalCharacterName
    |   '.'
    //|   // other implementation-defined characters...
    ;

fragment
Nondigit
    :   [a-zA-Z_]
    ;

fragment
Digit
    :   [0-9]
    ;

fragment
UniversalCharacterName
    :   '\\u' HexQuad
    |   '\\U' HexQuad HexQuad
    ;

fragment
HexQuad
    :   HexadecimalDigit HexadecimalDigit HexadecimalDigit HexadecimalDigit
    ;
```

[gramma file genenrate tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnjnZ.png)

Comment: Have you attempted anything already?

Comment: Not much have done.
Because my formated comments all start with "/*\n*|", so I want to discard the normal block comments and extract the formated comments out.
I'm not sure this can work?